# current.user.identity.name is null intermittently

Tags: identity, httpcontext

I am developing asp.net web application using VS 2008. I am using Windows    Authentication. I am trying to capture the current user name from
     `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.   It works absolutely fine on development system. After deploying the code to Test Environment(Windows server 2008R2), we notice that the
       `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is null intermittently. 
After adding the `<deny users="?">`, I am getting "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials." intermittently

IIS
Anonymous Authentication - disabled
Windows Authentication – enabled

web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The following change fixes the issue (not a single failed request) but after few hours the issue restarts.

IIS -> Sites -> My Project  -> Advanced Settings -> ID (Under General Section) ====> Changed this field (ID) to random number.

I thought this could due to app pool recycle so I set the app pool recycle time interval 0 ... but still the issue repeats after certain number of hours.